# Looking for differentiable functions $f$ such that the set of points at which $|f|$ is not differentiable has some particular properties

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know that $\sin x$ is differentiable at all points but $|\sin x|$ is not differentiable at countably many points namely at integer multiples of $\pi$ . So I am asking the following questions

i) Give example of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the set of points at which $|f|$ is  not differentiable is countable and dense in $\mathbb R$

ii) Give example of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the set of points at which $|f|$ is  not differentiable is uncountable and not dense in $\mathbb R$

iii) Give example of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the set of points at which $|f|$ is  not differentiable is uncountable and  dense in $\mathbb R$

$ UPDATE$:- As mentioned in the comments if $f$ is differentiable and and at some point non-zero then since by continuity $f$ will have same sign in a  neighborhood of that point , $|f|$ will be differentiable ; thus $|f|$ is not differentiable $c$ only when $f(c)=0$ but then as  John pointed out , if such points are dense then this leads to a contradiction , resolving i) and iii) in the negative ; this leaves us with (ii) only

Comment: What's your try?

Comment: Note that if $f$ is differentiable, then $|f|$ is not differentiable at $x$ only when $f(x) = 0$. This can help you to show that (i) and (iii) is not possible.

Comment: If $A=${ $x\in\mathbb{R}$ | $|f|$ is not differentiable }  is dense,
$ $

then $f(\mathbb{R})=f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline {f(A)} = \overline {\{0\}}=\{0\}$.
$ $

It implies $f$ is constant function(especially zero.). So. $|f|$ is constant function. 
$ $

Therefore $|f|$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.
$ $

This is CONTRADICTION to the density of $A$.
$ $

It will be answer of i), iii). $ $

Comment: true what about (ii) ?

Comment: @user123733: I am not sure about this one. Seems not to be an easy question.

Comment: @Thanks to both John and user143993 ; but we still have to get hold of (ii)

Answer (score 2):

I CLAIM THAT THE ANSWER TO (ii) IS NEGATIVE. PROOF.

Lemma: If $f$ is differentiable over $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ and $c$ is a SIMPLE zero of $f$ then it is isolated, it means there
exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $for$ all $x\in \left( c-\varepsilon
,c+\varepsilon \right) ,$ $f(x)=0$ iff $x=c.$ Proof. Assume the contrary
holds. Then there exists a sequence $x_{n}$ of zeros of $f$ converging to $c,
$ then $$f^{\prime }(c)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}%
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x_{n})-f(c)}{x_{n}-c}=\lim_{n\rightarrow
\infty }\frac{0-0}{x_{n}-c}=0.$$ Then $$f(c)=f^{\prime }(c)=0.$$ Contradicting
the simplicity of the zero $c.$

It follows that the Answer to (ii) is negative. In fact, every isolated subset
of $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ is countable.

Comment: Yes, Indeed, thank you ^^.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is incomplete but gives some results and extends the observation that the answer to questions (i) and (iii) is negative.
If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable, $|f|$ fails to be differentiable at a point $x\in\mathbb R$ if and only if $f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)\neq0$.
Continuity of $f$ follows from differentiability.
We are interested in the set $A=f^{-1}(0)\setminus(f')^{-1}(0)$ where $|f|'$ doesn't exist.

Some results:

1. $A$ is nowhere dense (its closure has empty interior).
   Reason:
   Suppose this is not the case.
   Then there is an open interval $I$ so that $A\cap I$ is dense in $I$.
   In particular this implies that $f^{-1}(0)\cap I$ is dense in $I$, which by continuity implies that $f|_I\equiv0$.
   It follows that also $f'|_I\equiv0$, a contradiction.
2. $A$ need not be closed even if $f'$ is continuous.
   Example:
   $f(x)=x^3\cos(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$.
   Now $f$ is continuously differentiable and $0\in\partial A\setminus A$.
   Zeros of $f$ accumulate at zero but the derivative doesn't vanish at other zeros.
3. If $f'$ is continuous, $A$ has zero measure.
   Reason:
   If $f$ is continuously differentiable, it is locally Lipschitz, and so is $|f|$.
   Lipschitz functions are differentiable almost everywhere by Rademacher's theorem, so the set of nondifferentiability has to have zero measure.

It seems that $A$ should be something like a Cantor set if we want it to be uncountable.
I faintly recall seeing a paper in arXiv where the author(s?) constructs a function which vanishes on the ternary Cantor set but its derivative is nonzero in this set.
Unfortunately I couldn't find the paper, and advice against taking my memory as a decisive argument.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. For your last paragraph, earlier someone gave an answer (now deleted) and the Cantor like construction is actually given. But the problem is, we want a differentiable $f$ so that $|f|$ satisfy the condition. I am not sure how such a differentiable $f$ could be made.

Comment: A continuous function which vanishes on a given closed set is easy to construct (the distance function to that set), but differentiability and nonvanishing derivative at the set is quite difficult. The function $f$ must change sign at every point of $A$, and making this uncountably many times is not easy.

Comment: REMARK: If one is able to give an example of a differentiable function f:R→R such that the set of points at which |f| is not differentiable is uncountable and not dense in R, then this same function f is differentiable over R and admits a set of SIMPLE zeros uncountable and not dense. So this is a necessary condition. My question is: Is it possible to give an example of a differentiable function f:R→R such that the set of simple zeros is uncountable and not dense in R? (only!)