# verify statement for |f(x)| is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> I proved the following 'origin' statement
>
> > If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c$ and
> >     $f(c)=0$ ,
> >
> > then the following are equivalent:
> >
> > (a) $g(x)=|f(x)|$ is differentiable at $c$
> >
> > (b) $f'(c)=0$

$$
$$

**NOW I made a statement** similar with origin statement

> > If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ ,
> >
> > then the following are equivalent:
> >
> > (a)' $g(x)=|f(x)|$ is differentiable at $c$
> >
> > (b)' 1. $f(c)\not=0$   $ $  or $  $    2. $f(c)=0$ and $f'(c)=0$

$$
$$

Question 1.

Is my statement right thing?

$$
$$

Question 2.

I think (intuitively) the sentence (b)' have to modifiy to [[ 
(b)''  $f(c)\not=0$   $ $  or $  $    $f'(c)=0$  ]]

Is (a)' $\Leftrightarrow$ (b)' $\Leftrightarrow$ (b)''  right?

$$
$$

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: $f(x) = x$, $c=0$ is a counter example to the statement you claim to have proven.

Comment: @Henrik For function f(x)=x, f'(x)=1 ... Could you tell me why this is counterexample?

Comment: @Henrik: I think that is not a counterexample? The statement in the first box is true.

Comment: $f$ is differentible at on $\mathbb R$, $f(0)=0$ but $g(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: @user143993: (b)' and (b)'' are equivalent as "$P$ or ($\sim P$ and $Q$)" is the same as "$P$ or $Q$".

Comment: I think the 'origin statement' says... (a) implies (b) and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the "TFAE".

Comment: @John WOW... SET THEORY?!... BTW, What do you think about 'my statement'? Is this right??

Comment: Your statement is true. You have proved one of them by assuming $f(c)=0$. For $f(c)\neq 0$, might be it is easier?

Comment: @John In case $f(c)\neq0$ , If $f(c)>0$ then can suppose $f(x)>0$ for some neighborhood of c... :-) . $f(c)<0$ is similar.  I've proved like this.

Comment: @user143993: That's correct. If you have time, please take a look at this related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028911/looking-for-differentiable-functions-f-such-that-the-set-of-points-at-which

Comment: Only if you have time.......^^

Comment: The first few comments on this post show why one should not use abbreviations in questions. It leads to misunderstandings.

Comment: @DavidK I will keep in mind. Thanks :-)

Comment: @John Thanks for introducing good problem.